# How to add a URL String in a JSON object

Tags: java, json

I need to add a URL typically in the format http:\somewebsite.com\somepage.asp. 
When I create a string with the above URL and add it to JSON object json

using

```
json.put("url",urlstring);
```

it's appending an extra "\" and when I check the output it's like `http:\\\\somewebsite.com\\somepage.asp`

When I give the URL as `http://somewebsite.com/somepage.asp`
the json output is `http:\/\/somewebsite.com\/somepage.asp`

Can you help me to retrieve the URL as it is, please?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using backslashes in your URL? URLs only use forward-slashes. The first URL is also not syntactically correct. It should be something like `http://somewebsite.com/somepage.asp`.

Comment: If you're looking at JSON string produced by serializer - it's ok to have slashes escaped. Slashes will be unescaped when JSON string is deserialized.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your JSON library automatically escapes characters like slashes. On the receiving end, you'll have to remove those backslashes by using a function like `replace()`.

Here's an example:

```
string receivedUrlString = "http:\/\/somewebsite.com\/somepage.asp";<br />
string cleanedUrlString  = receivedUrlString.replace('\', '');
```

`cleanedUrlString` should be `"http://somewebsite.com/somepage.asp"`.

Hope this helps.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)

Answer (score 4):

Tichodroma's answer has nailed it.  You can solve the "problem" by storing valid URLs.

---

In addition, the JSON format *requires* that backslashes in strings are escaped with a second backslash.  If the 2nd backslash is left out, the result is invalid JSON.  Refer to the JSON syntax diagrams at http://www.json.org

The fact that the double backslashes are giving you problems actually means that the software that is reading the files is broken.  A properly written JSON parser will automatically de-escape the strings.  The site I linked to above lists many JSON parser libraries written in many languages.  You should use one of these rather than trying to write the JSON parsing code yourself.