# How to format URL in JSON output?

Tags: json, url

I am using JSON output.

I am getting below output:

```
{"short_url":"http:\/\/urlhere\/fb\/37xzk"}
```

but I need:

```
{  
"short_url":"http: //urlhere/fb/37xzk"  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a URL String in a JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941768/how-to-add-a-url-string-in-a-json-object)

Answer (score 0):

You can format the url by using `replace()` function.

For Example:

```
    string url=jsonName.get("short_url");
    string formattedUrl=url.replace('\', '');
```