# Problem With adding an LinkedHashMap to an array inside of JSON object

Tags: java, json, eclipse, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I have this LinkedHashMap `{Label=BEER, ID=179039, URL=https://website.website.com/browse/178974/178973/179039, Children=[]}`

I also have a JSONObject with a single ArrayList inside of it like this: `{"Categories":[]}`

I am trying to append this LinkedHashmap to the array inside of the JSONObject, something like this:

`{"Categories":[{Label=BEER, ID=179039, URL=https://website.website.com/browse/178974/178973/179039, Children=[]}]}`

However when i do, and i print to the console, this is the output `{"Categories":[{"link":"","URL":"https:\/\/Website.Website.com\/browse\/178974\/178973\/179039","Children":[]}]}`

As you can see, the URL has come out wrong, and I am unsure as to why. Here is my code:

````
LinkedHashMap<String,Object> jo=new  LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
       jo.put("link", "");
       jo.put("URL", "https://Website.Website.com/browse/178974/178973/179039");
       jo.put("Children",new ArrayList<>());
       List<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>> categories = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>>();
       categories.add(jo);
       JSONObject ja1 = new JSONObject();
       ja1.put("Categories",categories);
       System.out.println(ja1);```
````

Note, this happens when I also simply just add the LinkedHashmap to the JSONObject EG:

```
{"Categories":{"link":"","URL":"https:\/\/Website.Website.com\/browse\/178974\/178973\/179039","Children":[]}}
```

I am using import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

Does anyone know why it is coming out incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Using your code with :

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

I also have this string :

```
{"Categories":[{"link":"","URL":"https:\/\/Website.Website.com\/browse\/178974\/178973\/179039","Children":[]}]}
```

Using your code with

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

I have the following result:

```
{"Categories":[{"link":"","Children":[],"URL":"https://Website.Website.com/browse/178974/178973/179039"}]}
```

But if you desired to keep using `org.json.simple.JSONObject;` you might look up this page : [How to add a URL String in a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941768/how-to-add-a-url-string-in-a-json-object)

Comment: May I ask how you imported that? as when I try to I get The import org.json.JSONObject cannot be resolved

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA and Maven so it is mainly automated. If you are using Maven you need to the following text add between the tag <dependencies> of your pom.xml file : 
`<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20160810</version>
</dependency>
`

Comment: If you want to keep your JSON library, use : 
`System.out.println("org.json.simple.JSONObject toString() : "+ja1);
String stringModified = ja1.toString().replace("\\", "");
System.out.println("org.json.simple.JSONObject toString() modified : "+stringModified);`
-->
org.json.simple.JSONObject toString() : {"Categories":[{"link":"","URL":"https:\\\/\\\/Website.Website.com\\\/browse\\\/178974\\\/178973\\\/179039","Children":[]}]}
org.json.simple.JSONObject toString() modified : {"Categories":[{"link":"","URL":"https://Website.Website.com/browse/178974/178973/179039","Children":[]}]}